# What is going on in my code for Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been searching for an answer to this, but I cannot seem to understand the solutions proposed in relation to my particular issue.

The Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
    MainActivity$Uploadimg.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:2213)
    MainActivity$Uploadimg.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:2126)
```

Here is the first one line 2213

```
LoginResponse mLoginResponse = mGson.fromJson(result, LoginResponse.class);
```

Here is the second one line 2126

```
public class Uploadimg extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
```

Comment: BTW This worked fine previously, and as far as I know nothing has changed really...

Comment: Please post the JSON in `result` and the definition of `LoginResponse` the issue is that JSON can not be converted into a LoginResponse object. We would have to see the request info to help you determin why.